# Is there a release event for HTML select element when the dropdown is released

Tags: html, events, select

As the title says, I need an event when dropdown is released for restoring something. I tried onblur and it may miss some releases.

Comment: perhaps you could watch on change, but does not fire when the value has not been changed (if user selects same value a second time).

Comment: How about http://api.jquery.com/mouseup/?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `onclick`. This fires whenever you will click on the select box however you select something or not.